# What are the consequences if I don't close an unused bank account in Netherlands?

Tags: netherlands, banking, legal

I have left Netherlands and I couldn't close the bank account there as I still had some payments to be received. Now my account shows negative balance. What are the consequences of not closing the account and leaving it as it is?

The bank in questions is ING bank and I have a negative balance of about 4.40€. I have already left Netherlands as I was there as an exchange student and my Visa has expired.

Answer (score 1):

Close it and forget.

Closing the account remotely is the easiest solution. It won't take you more than a couple of minutes. There's no need to be physically present in The Netherlands to do it. First transfer some money into the account to bring the balance to 0 - you never know whether you'll need them again, so do not burn bridges.

[Here is the Dutch page explaining how to cancel your personal account](https://www.ing.nl/particulier/betalen/betaalrekening-opzeggen/index.html)